# How to skip null collection inside array when doing a foreach

Tags: laravel

I have an array of collection like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1401 ▼
    #items: []
    #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  }
  1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1405 ▼
    #items: array:4 [▼
      0 => {#1407 ▼
        +"id": "887923fe-1993-4e5b-8a99-699d66be129c"
        +"employee_id": "887923fe-1993-4e5b-8a99-699d66be129c"
        +"in_time": "2022-01-10 11:31:44"
```

There's a null `#items:` inside it. And whenever I'm trying to loop the data, I always got error `property not exist`. I know it because the first collection item in my array is null. But I don't know how to skip it.

I've tried to use `isNotEmpty()`, but still got the error

```
@foreach ($attendance as $data)
    @if ($data->isNotEmpty())
     <td>{{ $data->name ?? '' }}</td>
     <td>{{ $data->alias ?? '' }}</td>
     ...
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the result of `isNotEmpty()` method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 approach.

**First**, checking `null` data in `loop` by counting the `array`

```
// Blade
@foreach ($attendance as $data)
    @if (count($data) > 0)
     <td>{{ $data->name ?? '' }}</td>
     <td>{{ $data->alias ?? '' }}</td>
     ...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Or**, checking in database with `Eloquent` method `whereNotNull`, so `null` data will not appear in your blade `variable`

```
// Eloquent
Model::whereNotNull('column_name')
```

[Laravel 8.x, Database: Query Builder, additional-where-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

Use **@if** to check for **NULL**

```
@foreach ($attendance as $data)
    @if (!empty($data))
        <td>{{ $data->name ?? '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->alias ?? '' }}</td>
        ...
```